# ¿Autorresponder va con doble ere o una erre?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, ortografía

Quisiera saber si al juntar dos palabras, y que la segunda empieza con **R (erre)**, ¿Se debe escribir con doble erre, es decir, una erre, con una erre?

Ejemplo:

> Auto + Responder = Autorresponder o Autoresponder ?

Otro ejemplo puede ser:

> Auto + Replicante = Autorreplicante o autoreplicante ?

¿Es lo mismo para todas las palabras que cumplen estas condiciones?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sí, aunque depende del prefijo.

> En las palabras compuestas con prefijo, debe escribirse rr si la posición del sonido vibrante múltiple es intervocálica: infrarrojo, vicerrector, contrarréplica (aunque estas mismas palabras, sin prefijo, se escriban con una sola r: rojo, rector, réplica)
>
> Fuente: [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=rw5vgdMxbD6BZt8pbI)

Esta letra `r` solo se deja sin duplicar cuando el prefijo o primer elemento compositivo termina en consonante porque se trata de duplicar el sonido de `rr` (erre doble) que tiene la `r` al principio de palabra.

> En las palabras compuestas, cuando el primer elemento termina con una vocal y el segundo empieza con erre, **es preciso duplicar la erre para mantener su sonido**: anti- + reumático no da antireumático, sino antirreumático (donde se pronuncia como erre). Del mismo modo, el prefijo pre- y el sustantivo rebajas forman prerrebajas, y no pre-rebajas o prerebajas.
>
> Fuente: [Fundéu en *la grafía rr en palabras compuestas*](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/rr-erre-doble-en-palabras-compuestas-940/)

aunque en el mismo enlace se explica que

> Sin embargo, es frecuente encontrar: farmacoresistente (por farmacorresistente), nanorobot (por nanorrobot), contrarevolucionario (por contrarrevolucionario), georadar (por georradar), pararayos (por pararrayos), autoretrato (por autorretrato), puertoriqueño (por puertorriqueño) o termoregulador (por termorregulador).

que simplemente son casos extendido de mala formación de estas palabras.

Answer (score 2):

La doble "rr" se contrae en una sola cuando está al comienzo de la palabra. Es el caso de "responder", que se pronuncia "rresponder" pero al estar en una palabra compuesta como "autorresponder" regresa a su estado original con "rr", puesto que en español no existen palabras que se pronuncien con una sola "r" al inicio.